# Handle null value in Dart / Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this User class and then a Firestore Document, that may or may not contain a photoURL or some other values. The problem is, that when I try to create an user I get this exception because some of the values are Null.

I've tried to handle it like this:

```
var photoURL = snapshot.data['photoURL']  ??= '';
```

but it seems it doesn't work.

Can anyone explain best practices handling Null values in Dart/Flutter respectively?

EDIT: I'm checking if snapshot.exists before and if I create the user omitting the values I know are Null, it creates it properly.

EDIT 2: I've found the problem appears when I try to handle empty List like this:

```
var favorites =  snapshot.data['favorites'] ?? [''];
```

Comment: are you doing `snapshot.hasData` check before looking for `'photoURL'` ?

Comment: if (snapshot.exists)

Comment: i've tried this before and it doesn't work, then I've read this article https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb and I've changed it to ??=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I was initialized the value the wrong way when I converted it to Json.

I handle the empty Array like this

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
   'favorites' : favorites ?? '',
}
```

when it should be:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
   'favorites' : favorites ?? [''],
}
```

So it was throwing when I tried to assign an empty Array to String.

Comment: just so you know `['']` is not an empty array. It's an array containing 1 element, an empty string. An empty array would be `[]`